# ValueError: Expected 2D array, got scalar array instead: array=6.5

Tags: python-3.x, scikit-learn, non-linear-regression

While practicing Support Vector Regression Model I got this error:

```
ValueError: Expected 2D array, got scalar array instead:
array=6.5.
Reshape your data either using array.reshape(-1, 1) if your data has a single feature or array.reshape(1, -1) if it contains a single sample.
```

This is my code (Python 3.7)

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
"""
Created on Mon Sep 20 14:39:06 2021

@author: lulu
"""

# SVR
# simple learning regression 
# Data preprocessing 
# Importing the libraries 
import numpy as np 
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt 
import pandas as pd # import data sets and manage data sets

# Importing dataset
dataset = pd.read_csv('/home/lulu/machineLearning/Position_Salaries.csv')
X = dataset.iloc[:, 1:2].values
y = dataset.iloc[:, 2].values


# Splitting the dataset into the training set and test set 
"""from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X,y,test_size = 1/3,random_state = 0)"""

# Feature scaling
from sklearn.preprocessing import StandardScaler
sc_X = StandardScaler() 
sc_y = StandardScaler()
X = sc_X.fit_transform(X)
y = sc_X.fit_transform(y)


# Fitting SVR to the training set
# Create your regressor here 
from sklearn.svm import SVR 
regressor = SVR(kernel = 'rbf')
regressor.fit(X, y)

# Producing a new result 
y_pred = regressor.predict(sc_X.transform(6.5))

# Visualizing the test VR results 
plt.scatter(X, y, color='red')
plt.plot(X, regressor.predict(X),color = 'blue')
plt.title('Truth or Bluff (SVR)')
plt.xlabel('Position level')
plt.ylabel('Salary')
plt.show()
```

I want to predict a new result and so since 6.5 is in some way not transformed we actually need to transform it with the following function but i don't know how i apply this function correctly

```
sc_X.transform
```

I want to know why i don't get a result ideal according to ground about multiple linear regression and so forth. The result is a senseless, i can't formulate a conclusion.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
y_pred = regressor.predict(sc_X.transform([[6.5]]))
```